# Eclipse 32 bits running on 64 bits JVM

Tags: java, eclipse, 64-bit, jvm

After many investigations I can't find a clear answer to the following question: Can Eclipse 32 bits version runs on a 64 bits JVM (of course on a 64 bits windows) ?

I guess the answer should be "NO" but I never worked with 64 bits systems and will be interested to "learn more" of how it work.

Thanks in advance,

Manu

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, that's not possible, because Eclipse's SWT GUI toolkit depends on native libraries (which is the reason there are separate 32 and 64bit version of eclipse in the first place), and [you cannot call 32bit native libraries from a 64bit JVM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_native_porting) (or, in general, you cannot mix 64bit and 32bit code within the same OS process).

Comment: Its possible though on Linux. Download the 32bit libraries and a 32bit VM, execute Eclipse on this vm with the -vm <path> argument

Comment: @Roo: I don't see how that's relevant to a question about running 32bit eclipse on a 64bit JVM.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need eclipse to be running as 64-bit unless you intend to use well over 1 GB for the IDE. You can use eclipse to develop 64-bit applications by configuring it to use a 64-bit JVM when running your application.

Note: Java switches between 32-bit and 64-bit transparently (not as simple for native libraries but this can be done also)  This means that developing for a 64-bit application looks and smells exactly the same as a 32-bit application.  All you get is the warm inner feeling knowing that you are using 64-bit machine code and a bit more memory. Note: using CompressedOops reduces the memory overhead at the cost of some CPU overhead.

If you need to use more than a few GB of memory, that is when 64-bit make a difference, but your code will be exactly the same and no re-compile is required.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using a 32 bit version on 64 version for quite some time and have not faced any problem till now.
 In most of the cases running a 32 bit version on 64 bit version should not be a problem but the other way would be a problem.

BR,
Keshav

Comment: Thanks. Since a JVM is a virtual machine/OS, it makes sense that it would behave like an OS. (E.g. Windows 64-bit can also run 32-bit programs, but not vice versa.)

Comment: But are you sure you've been doing this specifically with Eclipse (i.e. Eclipse is 32-bit and you *only* have a 64-bit JRE on your system)? The Eclipse FAQ says No, but maybe the issues are subtle? http://wiki.eclipse.org/IRC_FAQ#I_just_installed_Eclipse_on_my_64-bit_system.2C_but_it_does_not_start._What_is_the_problem.3F

Answer (score 1):

Also, running in 64 bit will add an unnecessary overhead of 5-8%.  Right now, 64 bit JVM should only be used for server programs needing large chunck of working memory.

Comment: This was try in Java 6 update 0, however Java 6 update 21 performs faster for most tasks in 64-bit mode.