# 32 bit Eclipse: JRE and JDK versions needed

Tags: java, eclipse

Apologies in advance. I know this is a basic question.

I am new to server administration. I am administering a server where the users do Java development.

They have a Java-based application and do development in Eclipse. Eclipse is 32-bit. The OS is 64-bit.

I recently updated the JDK and JRE on the server. I have both the 64-bit and 32-bit of each installed.

Eclipse ran into an error where it couldn't start after I had updated to the new JRE and JDK. So I took some advice online and updated the -vm path in the Eclipse .INI file to point to the new 32-bit JRE path. It now works.

I have two main questions:

1. Will updating the JRE and JDK EVER cause an issue with development, or as long as they can open up Eclipse and use at least one version of the JRE or JDK, they will be fine? I guess my fear is that they are going to develop in a certain version and the next version will cause issues down the line.
2. They develop in 32-bit Eclipse (not sure why they chose 32-bit) but their application runs with 64-bit Java (that is where the path points to for that installation). If something is developed in 32-bit Eclipse can it run with 64-bit Java? Side question: is there a certain advantage with developing with 32-bit Eclipse on a 64-bit system or is it personal choice?

Thanks a lot and cheers!

Comment: The JDK includes the JRE... You only need the JDK for development and the JRE on any computer simply running the  code

Comment: Do _NOT_ touch the eclipse.ini file unless you know what you are doing (which you don't).  Instead install a JRE so there is a globally available "java" command for Eclipse to use and tell the programmers where you put the JDK.

Comment: I have a JRE installed, and I updated the path, but for some reason it did not see it. What is the disadvantage, if any, of manually setting the path in the eclipse.ini file under "-vm"?

Answer (score 0):

> I guess my fear is that they are going to develop in a certain version and the next version will cause issues down the line.

Java 6 and 7 are end of life; Java 8 code should still be run when Java 9+ rolls out. I've not been aware of any backwards compatibility issues in recent years, it's only forward compatibility that doesn't work (running Java 8 compiled libraries with JRE 7).

> They develop in 32-bit Eclipse (not sure why they chose 32-bit) but their application runs with 64-bit Java

The IDE and code run in separate processes. There's no harm in using the 64bit JDK with 32bit editor.

[Eclipse 32 bits running on 64 bits JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785530/eclipse-32-bits-running-on-64-bits-jvm)

[Should I use Eclipse 32bits or 64bits on my new machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652677/should-i-use-eclipse-32bits-or-64bits-on-my-new-machine?rq=1)

Comment: 32 bit require all in all less memory.  Useful for multiple instances running at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

> Will updating the JRE and JDK EVER cause an issue with development...

I believe it technically could render what you developed "obsolete" if you're initially using one JDK with some specs and change for another one with specs that are not "compatible" with what you built so far. By specs, I mean the libraries, tools, etc that the JDK contains. But I would say it would be unlikely that such problems occur. It personally never happened to me. I'd like to have someone with more knowledge give more details though and validate what I'm saying or correct me if I'm wrong.

> If something is developed in 32-bit Eclipse can it run with 64-bit
>   Java?

To my knowledge, there are not related things. In my mind, Eclipse is just your IDE and it allows you to build/compile code using specific JDK (32 or 64 bits). As a matter of fact, you don't even need eclipse to build code but you definitely need a JDK: it's the JDK that give you the tools to compile code that "targets" a specific JRE/JVM and Eclipse is using the tools your JDK provide.
So yes, you can use eclipse 32 bits to build code for a 64 bits JRE.